# Detect thread end

Tags: multithreading, c++11

How can I detect when a thread was ended (in a platform independent way)?
I have to store copies of objects for every thread and I want to know when I can dispose or redistribute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possibly via RAII and local_thread mechanism. We create a class that do usefull work in destructor.

```
class ThreadEndNotifer
{
public:
    ~ThreadEndNotifer()
    {
        // Do usefull work
        useFullWork();
    }
}
```

Next, we create `local_thread` variable. It can be global or class feild(thread_local class field is implicit static).

```
class Foo 
{
private:
    // Remember about initialization like static feild
    thread_local ThreadEndNotifer mNotifer; 
}
```

So, the `useFullWork` will be called every time when any thread are ending. 
I like to create one global variable and init it only if needed, in this way I avoid overhead.

Answer (score 0):

With multiple threads, in order to detect any one of them was ended, you need:

A shared `condition_variable` for notification, a shared `mutex` to lock, and shared variables for conditions of all threads.

```
void call_me_at_the_end_of_a_thread(int index_of_thread){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(the_global_mutex);
    array_of_bools[index_of_thread] = true;
    num_of_dead_threads++; // global integer only for the convenience of checking before wait
    std::notify_all_at_thread_exit(the_global_condition_variable, std::move(l));
}
```

You may use an array of bool or `vector<bool>` for checking which threads was ended. You may prefer `notify_all` to `notify_all_at_thread_exit` if you don't care about the timing of notifying after current thread has finished "completely".

```
void call_me_to_detect_thread_was_ended(void){
    static int copy_of_num_of_dead_threads;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(the_global_mutex);
    while(num_of_dead_threads==copy_of_num_of_dead_threads)
        the_global_condition_variable.wait(l);
    std::cout<<num_of_dead_threads - copy_of_num_of_dead_threads<<" threads finished.\n";
    copy_of_num_of_dead_threads=num_of_dead_threads;
}
```

`num_of_dead_threads` is only for simplicity. Check the `array_of_bools` to find out which threads have already finished.